# Transferring ownership of NFT(ERC721)

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js, erc721

I'm trying to change the ownership of a requested ERC721(NFT) to another wallet.

I'm using the Mumbai Test Net and ethers.

To do it I need to create the general ERC721 contract using its abi but I can't find it.

In comparison, the ERC20's abi I found easily - [link](https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/) and used it like followed and it's working:

```
const createERC20Contract = (contractAddress) => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const ERC20Contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ERC20ABI, signer);

    return ERC20Contract;
}
```

Where can I find the abi of ERC721 to create the ethers.Contract() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic ERC721 ABI that I built from the OpenZeppelin [implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.5.0/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol). (The bare minimum contract - none of their extensions such as mint and burn tokens.)

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "name_",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "symbol_",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ApprovalForAll",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getApproved",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "isApprovedForAll",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ownerOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "safeTransferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bytes",
                "name": "_data",
                "type": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "name": "safeTransferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setApprovalForAll",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bytes4",
                "name": "interfaceId",
                "type": "bytes4"
            }
        ],
        "name": "supportsInterface",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "bool",
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "tokenURI",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :)
It's now working with 'transferFrom' and not 'safeTransferFrom'. But it is good enough for now. 
What is the best practice for transferring ownership of NFT? To transfer it on the client-side using like I've shown here? or use the IERC721 in the .sol file?

Comment: @AlonBenYaakov It depends on your use case. Mind that for client-side transfer, you'll need the token owner to sign a transaction performing the transfer (e.g. through their MetaMask wallet). For a transfer through a third-party contract, your contract needs to be an owner or an operator of this NFT (the user needs to `approve()` your contract to operate their token).